# What is the correct pipeline to work with Link prediction using GNNs

Tags: python, graph-neural-network

Trying to understand GNNs better, I copied the code from this [blog post](https://medium.com/@pytorch_geometric/link-prediction-on-heterogeneous-graphs-with-pyg-6d5c29677c70) from PyG documentation. I copied and pasted the code without modifications, which works as described in the post. It is a link prediction on the MovieLens dataset.

After the training loop with a reasonable accuracy score, I want to use the trained Model to predict new links in an unseen dataset.

To do it, I re-run the previous code with the extra following line:

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), "my_path.pth")
```

My second step then is to create a new script to use the trained model to predict new links:

The script is something like copying the first 40 lines of the previous script (to load movies and users again) and trying to predict the links:

```
checkpoint = torch.load("my_path.pth", map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
model = Model(hidden_channels=64)

model = model.to(device)
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint)

batch_size = 32  # Set the batch size for the DataLoader
shuffle = False  # Do not shuffle the data during iteration
num_workers = 0  # Set the number of worker threads for loading the data (0 for no parallelization)

new_dataloader = LinkNeighborLoader(
    data,
    # Sample 30 neighbors for each node for 2 iterations
    num_neighbors=[20, 10],
    # Use a batch size of 128 for sampling training nodes
    batch_size=batch_size,
    edge_label_index=(("user", "rates", "movie"), (data["user", "rates", "movie"].edge_index)),
)


model.eval()
preds, probs, pred_labels = [], [], []
for _, batch in enumerate(new_dataloader):
    
    batch.to(device)

    pred = model(batch)

    preds.append(pred)
    prob = torch.sigmoid(pred)
    probs.append(prob)
    pred_labels.append((prob > 0.9).long())


print(len(pred_labels))
print(len(probs))
```

Instead of creating a new synthetic dataset, I tried using the data I used for training to check if the predictions would work properly. I purposely deleted some information about users and movies to have a different dataset size. However, it raises the error `size mismatch for movie_emb.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([9742, 64]) from checkpoint, the shape in the current model is torch.Size([9216, 64]).`

It makes sense because I used the number of nodes of my graph in the model definition (e.g., line `self.user_emb = torch.nn.Embedding(data["user"].num_nodes, hidden_channels)`), but now I'm wondering if it's mandatory always to use the same number of nodes for trained GNNs.

- Is this assumption correct?
- If so, is the standard pipeline for Link predictions always performing training with the knowledge links and then predicting the new ones?